# Unexpected difference in behaviour between using a thread using a Runnable and a derived Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Q:I need a detailed explanation on the outputs of the following codes... What is the difference for the thread created using runnable interface and the thread created directly by extending thread class...???

Q1:

```
public class BalanceChecker1{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        RunnableClass runnableClass=new RunnableClass();
        new Thread(runnableClass).start();
        new Thread(runnableClass).start();
    }
}

class RunnableClass implements Runnable{
    Bean bean=new Bean();
    public void run(){
        synchronized(bean){
            bean.incBalance();
        }
    }
}

class Bean{
    private int balance=0;
    public void incBalance(){
        balance++;
        System.out.println(" The thread name "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(" The balance is "+balance);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 The thread name Thread-0
 The balance is 1
 The thread name Thread-1
 The balance is 2
```

Q2:

```
public class BalanceChecker1{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new specialThread().start();
        new specialThread().start();
    }
}
class specialThread extends Thread{
    Bean bean=new Bean();
    public void run(){
        synchronized(bean){
            bean.incBalance();
        }
    }
}

class Bean{
    private int balance=0;
    public void incBalance(){
        balance++;
        System.out.println(" The thread name "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(" The balance is "+balance);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 The thread name Thread-0
 The thread name Thread-1
 The balance is 1
 The balance is 1
```

Answer (score 6):

The important difference between those two examples is **not** in `Runnable` vs. extending `Thread` (on an unrelated note: there's almost never a reason to extend `Thread`, you almost always want to implement `Runnable`.

The important difference is that in the first example both running threads share a common `Bean` object on which they synchronize! This means that the call to `incBalance()` can't be executed by both threads at once.

In the second example they have a separate `Bean` object each, so the synchronization has no practical effect.

Also note that the output you posted is not guaranteed: you could get the same output in the second example as in the first (you can't get the mixed output from the second example form the first, however).

Comment: He's using synchronize, so while it's not guaranteed to be in the order, it won't print out 1 twice like the second result

Comment: @Rob: that's what I wanted to imply. It's just that he presents the output as if it's the only possible output.